# An example of a statement that is true within a group, but that is unprovable from the group axioms?

Tags: group-theory, logic, model-theory, foundations

[We know that:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132936/theories-and-models)

> If our language is the group language $L_G = \{ e, \cdot \}$ and our theory is the three group axioms:
> $$ (i) \exists e \in G: \forall g \in G: eg = ge = g$$
> $$ (ii) \forall g \in G \exists g^{-1} \in G: gg^{-1} = g^{-1}g = e$$
> $$ (iii) \forall a,b,c \in G: a(bc) = (ab)c$$
> Then every group is a model of that theory.

For a given group of your choice:

1. Can you show me an example of a statement that is *true in that model*, but that at the same time is also not provable from these axioms? (The model of your choice should be described restrictively by this 3-axioms theory, no other axiom should be added).
2. Which additional axioms would be required to modify the theory in such a way that the statement becomes provable?
3. Can you tell me another model for which that same statement is false?

Comment: What exactly does the parenthetical "(The model of your choice should restrictively live in this 3-axioms theory, without any additional axiom describing your model)" mean? Also, what have you tried? Can you say anything about any specific example groups?

Comment: sure; consider for example the sentence $\theta\equiv\exists v(v\neq e)$. If $G$ is any non-trivial group, then $G\models\theta$. however, $\theta$ is not provable from the theory of groups, since it has the trivial group as a model

Comment: As in other comments and answer: I think you're not asking exactly the question you intend... You'd want axioms + some form of "specification of the group", I think.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be clearer: things provable just from the axioms are true for _every_ group, things "true" from the axioms are true for all. Things that are true/provable about particular groups of types of groups do not follow from the axioms alone, but need further details. Sure, these can be written as $A\Rightarrow B$, provable from the axioms, where $A$ is some additional assumptions/descriptions of the group at hand. In any case, the "word problem" was shown to be undecidable decades ago.

Comment: @paulgarrett if a statement is provable from the axioms of a theory, then it must be true in every model of the theory; if a statement is true only in some models of the theory, we can be sure that that statement does not follow from these axioms (godel's *completeness* theorem)

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you're wanting, but I am vaguely aware (from C. Weibel's very nice book on homological algebra) that answers to questions about (co)homological dimension of various things can depend on the continuum hypothesis... Presumably this could be encoded (if it isn't already...) into group theory...

Comment: Can you verify whether your question 1 is equivalent to the following? *For any group $G$ there exists a statement $\theta$ in the language $L_G$, and there exists a group $H$, such that $\theta$ is true in $G$ and $\theta$ is false in $H$.*

Comment: @paulgarrett In fact that can't happen - the question of whether a first-order sentence $\theta$ is provable from a first-order theory $T$ is "set-theoretically absolute." Part of the niceness of FOL is exactly that we *can't* bring stuff like CH into questions about first-order group theory.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah! Interesting! Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: @LeeMosher yes my question 1 should indeed be equivalent to your formulation. my formulation wanted to highlight the role of provability/axioms in order to relate to question 2

Comment: @NegentropySeeker Well, every group satisfies either $\forall x,y(x*y=y*x)$ or $\exists x,y(x*y\not=y*x)$, but neither of those sentences is a consequence of the group axioms since both abelian and non-abelian groups exist. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Regarding your question 2, once you've found a statement satisfying question 1 and 3 (e.g. either abelian or non-abelian as in the preceding comment of @NoahSchweber), you just adopt that statement as an axiom.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the model $G = \{e\}$, the trivial group. Then the statement $\forall x\in G : x =e$ is true in the model, but it obviously can't be proved from the axioms since there are groups with more than one element.

Comment: i'll ask a basic-fundamental question. **what is the difference between _choosing_ a model of a theory, and extending the axioms of the theory?** The axioms defining a theory live on a very abstract level of reality, and when we do the *action* of choosing a model we move to a different, less abstract & more specific situation, so i wonder if the axiomatic description of our theory really stays the same before and after this action.  For example in your answer, isn't the *action of choosing* the trivial group translatable to axiom #4: "={}" ?

Comment: @NegentropySeeker "$G=\{e\}$" isn't really a first-order sentence in the language of group theory (although something like "$\forall x(x=e)$" is and will do the job). Re: your bolded question in your comment, it sounds like you're looking for examples of *different* groups satisfying the *same* axioms (e.g. **elementarily equivalent** but **non-isomorphic**); does that sound right?

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, with different group satisfying the same axioms, what is the difference between **the action of choosing** a group (aka, moving to a slightly more specific & less abstract layer of reality) and extending the axioms of the theory? could we interprete the former as the latter (why or why not)?

Comment: @NegentropySeeker Every structure $\mathcal{M}$ has a corresponding complete theory $Th(\mathcal{M})$, namely the set of all sentences true in $\mathcal{M}$. However, two structures with the same theory can be very different. For example, by the compactness theorem (in its guise as the upward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem) every countably infinite group has the same theory as some *uncountable* group! So in fact specifying a group is **far more** powerful than merely adding additional axioms - even than adding *as many additional axioms as possible*!

Comment: For a concrete example, the groups $(\mathbb{Q};+)$ and $(\mathbb{R};+)$ are extremely non-isomorphic but satisfy all the same first-order sentences.

Comment: @NoahSchweber in your comment, "the complete theory of a model is the set of statements that is true in the model". However i've often read (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic))) that a theory is the set of sentences deducible from the axioms, which should be different, can you help me understand how to solve this apparent discrepancy?

Comment: @NegentropySeeker Any set of sentences determines a corresponding theory (its deductive closure), for which that original set of sentences is said to be an axiomatization. Different sets of sentences yield different theories, and that said a theory doesn't need to be introduced with a separate axiomatization - a theory is just a deductively closed set of sentences. So there's no tension here. (That said, there is some terminological difference - namely, some texts allow "theory" to refer to **any** set of sentences while others require deductive closure - but that's not really the issue here.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber i agree, but since "deducible from axioms" is not equivalent to "true", i have not fully understood why you mentioned that "a theory of a model is the set of statements that is *true* in the model". i need to sort this doubt out in order to fully appreciate your previous answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127652/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-negentropyseeker).

Answer (score 2):

Consider an abelian group $A$, for which, by definition, we have for all $a,b\in A$, $$ab=ba.$$ There exist nonabelian groups. Thus the axiom $\forall a,b\in A,\, ab=ba$ is true for some groups but not for others; it cannot, therefore, be derived from the group axioms.